# Tensorflow: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Tensorflow, and am trying to train a specific deep learning neural network. I am using Tensorflow (2.11.0) to get a deep neural network model which is described below. The data which I use is also given below:

**Data:**

Here is some example data. For sake of ease we can consider 10 samples in data. Here, each sample has shape: `(128,128)`.

One can consider the below code as example training data.

```
x_train = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128, 1)
```

**Normalization layer:**

```
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(x_train)
```

**Build model:**

```
def build_and_compile_model(norm):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      norm,
      layers.Conv2D(128, 128, activation='relu'),
      layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='relu'),
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
      layers.Dense(units=1)
    ])

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))
    
    return model
```

When I do

```
dnn_model = build_and_compile_model(normalizer)
dnn_model.summary()
```

I get the below error:

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. The input_shape received is (None, None, None, None), where axis -1 (0-based) is the channel dimension, which found to be `None`.
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

I have tried to get insights from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264676/tensorflow-valueerror-the-channel-dimension-of-the-inputs-should-be-defined-fo), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013918/valueerror-the-channel-dimension-of-the-inputs-should-be-defined-found-none), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978375/the-channel-dimension-of-the-inputs-should-be-defined-found-none) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881851/tensorflow-keras-model-load-error-valueerror-the-last-dimension-of-the-inputs). But, I have not found a workable solution yet.

What should I do to remove the error and get the model to work?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the input shape directly in the normalization layer (or add an `Input` layer), since it cannot be inferred directly:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_train = np.random.rand(10, 128, 128, 1)
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=[128, 128, 1], axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(x_train)


def build_and_compile_model(norm):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        norm,
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, 3, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
    ])

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

    return model


dnn_model = build_and_compile_model(normalizer)
dnn_model.summary()
```

Also, your model does not work as it is, you are using a kernel size of 128 in your first `Conv2D` layer and then another `Conv2D` layer with a kernel size of 3 but your data has the shape `(10, 128, 128, 1)`. I changed it to make your code executable.